# Two hashtags instead of one in href attribute for HTML Anchor tag

Tags: html, attributes, href, anchor, hashtag

I thought this would be simple to find the answer, but I'm not finding one. I know the purpose of one hashtag in the href attribute of an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#">
```

However, every so often I come across the following:

```
<a href="##">
```

Does two hashtags in the href attribute do something different than one hashtag, and if so, what?

Comment: Do not confuse fragment identifiers (links to a specific part of a webpage) with hashtags (search terms marked with a `#` that are used to generate search links on social media). Not everything starting with a hash character is a hashtag.

Comment: "However, every so often I come across the following" — Where? In what context?

Comment: Just in other people's code that I'm reviewing. No one that's around at that time, so I can't ask them. And I'm not talking about fragment identifiers. I'm just talking about the one hashtag you put in when you're just providing a dead link that goes nowhere (like when doing a flexbox/navbar exercise for class).

Comment: The blank fragment identifier is *not* a hashtag and is a link to the top of the page, not nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

That's usually written when you want your anchor tag to not change the href. For instance, if you want to attach an event to it later on.

It doesn't matter how many # you are using. The href='#' will make the page jump to the top of the page if clicked.

If you want the link to be broken, my preferred way is doing <a href="javascript:void(0);". That way the click does absolutely nothing, instead of jumping the page up.